# What is the use of Environment.NewLine and TextWriter.NewLine properties

Tags: c#, io, newline

I have a weird situation that I don't understand relating to newlines `'\n'` that I am sending to a file. The newlines do not seem to be treated the according to the `NewLine` properties of `TextWriter` and `Environment`. This code demonstrates:

```
String baseDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + '\\';
String fileName = baseDir + "deleteme5.txt";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
fi.Delete();
FileStream fw = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fw);
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine.Length);
Console.WriteLine(sw.NewLine.Length);
sw.Write("1\uf0f1\n2\ue0e1\n3\ud0d1\n");
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

When I run this the console output is

> 2 
>   2

When I look at my file in hex mode I get:

> 00000000h: 31 EF 83 B1 0A 32 EE 83 A1 0A 33 ED 83 91 0A    ;
>   1ïƒ±.2îƒ¡.3íƒ‘.

Clearly, the API says two characters and when you look in the file there is only one character. Now when I look to the description of the Write method in TextWriter it indicates that the Write method does not substitute 0A with the NewLine property. Well, if the Write method doesn't take that into account, what is the use of having not one but two NewLine properties? What are these things for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All newlines escaped as \n in a string are single-character ASCII newlines (0x0A) (not Windows newlines 0D0A) and output to streams in writers as 0x0A unless the programmer takes some explicit step to convert these within the string to the format 0D0A.

The TextWriter.NewLine property is used only by methods like WriteLine, and controls the formatting of the implicit newline that is appended as part of the invocation.

The distinction between `Environment.NewLine` and `TextWriter.NewLine` is that Environment.NewLine is readonly, only meant to be queried by programmers. (This is different from Java, for instance, where you can change the "system-wide" newline formatting default with `System.setProperty("line.separator", x);`

In C# you can modify the format of the implicit newline when writing using `TextWriter.NewLine`, which is initialized to `Environment.NewLine`. When using TextReader methods that read lines, there is no `TextReader.NewLine` property. The implicit newline behavior for readers is to break at any 0x0A, 0x0D, or 0D0A

As pointed out by rene the original problem could be resolved by writing:

```
sw.Write("1\uf0f1\n2\ue0e1\n3\ud0d1\n".Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine));
```

Answer (score 6):

Programmers have a very long history of *not* agreeing how text should be encoded when it is written to a file.  ASCII and Unicode helped level the Tower of Babel to some degree.  But what characters denote the ending of a line was never agreed upon.

- Windows uses the carriage return + line feed control codes.  `"\r\n"` in C# code.
- Unix flavors use just a single line feed control code, `'\n'` in C# code.
- Apple historically used just a single carriage return control code, `'\r'` in C# code.

.NET needed to be compatible with all these incompatible choices.  So it added the Environment.NewLine property, it has the default line ending sequence for your operating system.  Note how you can run .NET code on Unix and Apple machines with Mono or Silverlight.

The abstract TextWriter class needs to know what sequence to use since it writes text files.  So it has a NewLine property, its default is the same as Environment.NewLine.  Which you almost always use, but you might want to change it if you need to create a text file that's read by a program on another operating system.

The mistake you made in your program is that you **hard-coded** the line terminator.  You used '\n' in your string.  This completely bypasses the .NET properties, you'll only ever see the single line feed control code in the text file.  0x0A is a line feed.  Your console output displays "2" since that just displays the string length of the NewLine property.  Which is 2 on Windows for "\r\n".

The simplest way to use the .NET property is to use WriteLine() instead of Write():

```
  sw.WriteLine("1\uf0f1");
  sw.WriteLine("2\ue0e1");
  sw.WriteLine("3\ud0d1");
```

Which makes your code nicely readable as well, it isn't any slower at runtime.  If you want to keep the one-liner then you could use composite formatting:

```
  sw.Write("1\uf0f1{0}2\ue0e1{0}3\ud0d1{0}", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Your knowledge is surprisingly unbeatable.

Comment: I sincerely hope it is not a surprise :)

Answer (score 1):

If choose to generate the 'linebreaks' your self by sending \n to the streamwriter there is no way the framework is going to interfer with that. If you want the framework to honor the NewLine property use the WriteLine method of the writer and set the NewLine property of the Writer.

Adapt your code like so:

```
sw.NewLine = Environment.NewLine; // StreamWriter uses \r\n by default

sw.WriteLine("1\uf0f1")
sw.WriteLine("2\ue0e1");
sw.WriteLine("3\ud0d1");
```

Or have a Custom StreamWriter that overrides the Write method:

```
public class MyStreamWriter:StreamWriter
{
    public MyStreamWriter(Stream s):base(s)
    {
    }

    public override void Write(string s)
    {
        base.Write(s.Replace("\n",Environment.NewLine));
    }   
}
```

Or if you only have one line that you want to handle:

```
sw.Write("1\uf0f1\n2\ue0e1\n3\ud0d1\n".Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine));
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this that does not involve the overhead of making three method invocations instead of one? As I understand, `WriteLine` will take the `TextWriter.NewLine` property into account. I'm still left with the question what is the purpose of `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: To help clear up any misunderstanding for others reading the above comment: WriteLine(X) simply calls Write(X) followed by a call to WriteLine() - which in turn simply appends TextWriter.NewLine. In other words, TextWriter.NewLine simply determines what the TextWriter appends at the end of each WriteLine(X) call. Nothing more. It writes exactly what you send to it exactly as you sent it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use implicitly, as in calling a WriteLine method or explicitly as in Write(String.Concat("Hello", Environment.NewLine), you get the end of line character(s) defined for your environment. If you don't use it and use say '\n' or even '$', then you are saying no matter what environment I'm in, lines will end like I say. If you want to compare behaviour, write a bit of code and run it under windows and linux (mono)

Comment: Ah! are you saying the purpose of Environment.NewLine is mainly for the programmer to use, and TextWriter.NewLine is for the runtime to use? Well that makes some sense. I don't know why I have these two properties.

Comment: Didn't know that TextWriter had it's own, but I suspect it defaults to Environment's. Handy when a particular file is from or for a different environment, set it and then the rest of your code is agnostic.